# Reusable FlyoutPage on .NET MAUI and Prism

Tags: prism, maui

is it possible to create a FlyoutPage navigation where pages are reusable.

For example: The Flyout navigation in the [Prism.Maui.Demo](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Documentation) contains the view "SamplePage". This view has a button click counter. Is it possible that we use the same "SamplePage" in a Flyout navigation more than once so that when navigating to the "SamplePage" again, the value of the counter is the same as it was before we navigating away?

The Prism docu write:
When navigating with an Absolute URI, the Navigation Service will set a new Page on the Application Window. When navigating with a Relative URI, the Navigation Service will **push a new Page** onto the Navigation Stack.

In TabPage navigation it seems to be a default behavior.

Comment: If I understand correctly, do you mean a singleton?

Comment: to be precise: a singleton _service_. You don't want the page or the page's view model to be a singleton.

Comment: yes, someting like that. In a tabbedpage we can create tabs like:

/TabbedPage?createTab=ViewA&amp;createTab=ViewB&amp;createTab=ViewC&amp;createTab=ViewD&amp;createTab=SamplePage

each click to a tab icon shows the originally created page. Is such a behaviour also possible with flyout pages?

Comment: Each time we change a detail page, it seems create a new instance of that page, which is different from TabbedPage. Actually, if you want to store a value, you could use [Preferences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/pages/flyoutpage?view=net-maui-7.0) to store a value. Each time, you navigate to a detail page, just retrieve it.

Comment: additional note: Its a prism maui application